# Devise + OmniAuth Installation Error: undefined method `omniauth' for Devise:Module (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, omniauth

I'm working to allow users to FB Connect into my app for authentcation. My app currently uses devise so I'm following the tutorial here:

[https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth%3A-Overview](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth%3a-Overview)

After adding this to my gem file:

```
gem "oa-oauth", :require => "omniauth/oauth"
```

This to config/initializers/devise.rb:

```
config.omniauth :facebook, "APP_ID", "APP_SECRET"
```

This to app/models/User.rb

```
devise :omniauthable
```

After running bundle install, when I run rails s I get the error. Ideas why? Thanks

Comment: What version of devise are you using?

Comment: How did you fix this. I have installed the omniauth and the devise gem, but am still facing the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add 'omniauth' in gemfile and then try.

gem "omniauth" , "0.2.0"

My devise version is 1.3.3